# Nodejs + firebase : Can't delete multiple documents

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I did a script like this to delete old documents in my firebase collection but now it does not work. All was fine 2 weeks ago but not now.

I have this error

> Caused by: Error
> at WriteBatch.commit
> at DocumentReference.delete

```
let roomsRef = db.collection('rooms')
roomsRef.where('Timestamp', '<', tomorrow).get().then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
        functions.logger.log("No matching document");

        return;
    }
    snapshot.forEach(doc => doc.ref.delete()
        //doc.ref.delete()
        );
    return null;
}).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: That error message is rather vague. Is there any more information in the stack trace? If not, can you tell a bit more about what changed? For example: how many documents does your query return?

Comment: Hmm... on second viewing, the error mentions a `WriteBatch`, which I don't see anywhere in this code. Are you sure this is the code that is generating that error?